# Catch $http use $httpBackend in App.run

Tags: testing, angularjs

I have a module `App` which will check if the user has sign in.

```
App.run ['$rootScope', 'UserService', ($rootScope, UserService) ->
  UserService.current_user()
]
```

The `UserService.current_user()` will trigger a `$http` request.

So how can i write the $httpBackend to mockup the request? I have tried some method:

```
describe 'App', ->
  $httpBackend = null

  beforeEach(module('App')) # one
  beforeEach inject ($injector) -> # two
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend')
    $httpBackend
      .when('GET', '/api/1/users/current_user')
      .respond(403, {"error":"not signin"})


  it "should get current_user request", () ->
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/1/users/current_user').respond(403, {'error': 'not signin'})
```

This will show the error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/1/users/current_user No more request expected
```

If I change the sequence of `# one` and `# two`. It will show error

```
Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!
```

This makes me fall in depression. I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working with this :

```
describe 'App', ->
  beforeEach angular.mock.module('App')

  it "should get current_user request", inject ($httpBackend) ->
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/1/users/current_user').respond(403, {'error': 'not signin'})
    $httpBackend.flush()
```

And it works also if you put the backend expectation in a before each :

```
describe 'App', ->
  beforeEach angular.mock.module('App')
  beforeEach inject ($httpBackend) ->
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/1/users/current_user').respond(403, {'error': 'not signin'})
    $httpBackend.flush()

  it 'should test someting else', ->
```

See it in action in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MgNoFOY7Y1N8ylfW0Uvi?p=preview).

Comment: It shows the error: `Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!`.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work for me... `Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/1/users/current_user No more request expected`. I think the $http trigger when `angular.mock.module('App') run`.

Comment: The error looks like you flushing the httpBackend without declaring your expectation

Comment: Is there only one request GET '/api/1/users/current_user' sent when you start your app ? And if the first call return with a 403 ?

Comment: Yeah, only one request. And it return 403.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue and this solution is not working for me.

Comment: I add a plunker with unit test working. Can you fork it and make it fails ?